# Could not load translations: Invalid trailing UTF-8 octet in YAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

Im new to rails and trying to internationalize my app with I18n. In the locales yaml file for the spanish version im trying to set up the translations as follows:

```
es:
  categories: "Categorias"
  home: Inicio
  live_casino: "Casino en Vivo"
  sportsbook: Deportes
```

This works like a charm, but as soon as I add the accent in the spanish word like this:

```
categories: "Categorías"
```

Rails gives me the following error:

```
I18n::InvalidLocaleData in WelcomeController#index
can not load translations from .../config/locales/es.yml: #<Psych::SyntaxError: (.../config/locales/es.yml): invalid trailing UTF-8 octet at line 1 column 1>
```

Ive tried everything ive found in the web and nothing has worked please help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I opened the locale file in Notepad++ and noticed it was encoded in "UTF-8 w/o BOM".

Click on `Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8`  and the error went away.

Comment: In case you're using Textmate – I used the same basic technique via  `File/Re-open With Encoding/UTF8`, then saving the file. YAML load then worked. Before I changed it, the checkmark in the menu was on `ISO-8859-1 (Latin 1)`.

Comment: The file that I was using was encoded in ANSI. So from Notepad++ I had to click on `Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8`

Comment: Same with UltraEdit. Also the error Rails reported was in a file which hadn't been touched in months and didn't actually have any translation calls in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the following line at the beginning of the es.yml file:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, in my case, I had : in the middle of the text, but : is functional sign so get rid of it, this can be caused by any signs that has been copied from online or ord and pasted.